# Remove All Untracked File Into Git Directory?

Tags: git

Hello my problem is simple.

I am try to remove all untracked file into my current git directory. I use some git command but it is not working properly that command look like that.

```
 git clean -f, git clean -f -d, git clean -f -X, git clean -f -x, but anybody not work properly
```

When I type git status any untrack file not remove from directory.Due to this problem I do not push my work on git. someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem as I understand is you don't want to commit or push some files when they are not ready. You can try to add them to ignored list or uncheck them on git push screen if you are using any  git client.

Comment: I Also Try This Tricks But Result Is Zero.

Comment: Are you using any client?I generally use tortoiseGit for this purpose, When i commit at any point it shows me a list of all file that are already added to git and any untracked or new file that are not part of repository.Now if I uncheck them on commit they are not committed and does not get pushed.However they are still there in my local repository and workspace.Since such file are not part of the git I can do the dirty work manually deleting them.